# My function call outside of the class is not working in Scrapy / Python

Tags: python, function, scrapy

```
def printer (param1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11):
    print(f"Here is param1: {param1}")
    #actual stuff happens
    item_data = item()
    item_data["item characteristic1"] = variable
    item_data["item characteristic2"] = variable
    yield item(**item_data)

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = [URL]

    def parse(self, response):
        #gets nested URL and sends to parsenestedurl()

    def parsenestedurl(self, response):
        #does stuff
        print("we made it")
        printer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

So I have code similar to that shown above and I can see I am going through `parsenestedurl()` just fine and it always prints `we made it` but it never gets to the `printer` function and prints the first statement `print(f"Here is param1: {param1}")` what am I doing wrong here?  I know I have a lot of parameters but that should technically not matter right?

Edit:

So I was messing around in my code and there is a yield function at the end of printer.  When I comment the yield out of `printer()` it works totally fine so it is something with the yield.

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of your first line.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: I actually just mistyped it for this question but it is correct in the actual code.  IO just edited it above @DanielWalker  But I am getting no errors!

Comment: Can you show your full code?  Nowhere in your displayed code do you call `parsenestedurl`.

Comment: I call that function correctly in my code but I can't show my full code just due to its commercial potential.  But if it helps the printer function in my actual code is called `item_creator()`

Comment: @DanielWalker Check the edit!

Comment: `printer` is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `printer` function is a generator to have any output `parsenestedurl` would be like:

```py
def parsenestedurl(self, response):
    #does stuff
    print("we made it")
    a = printer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
    yield next(a)
```

Or change the `printer` to simple function and

```py
return item(**item_data)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Scrapy?  I kind of have an add-on question that is a slight branch off of this.

Comment: Ask it, I'll try to help

Comment: There are actually multiple different items in the `printer ()` function and when I do 

`yield item1(**item1_data)
yield item2(**item2_data)`

the only item that ever goes through my item pipeline is the first yielded item.  How can I send multiple items through my item pipeline at one time?

Comment: I actually figured it out nvm.